# Fill new column in df based on many conditions in df2 and df3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dfs. df1 contains 46 columns. df2 and df3 contain 41 columns and contain threshold values for columns in df1 which indicate if it needs a repeat or repeat with addition. Below are simplified examples

df1:

```
 |Name | A   | B   | C  |.......
------------------------------
0|ID1  | 10  | 2   | 3  |
1|ID2  | 400 | 1   | 6  |
2|ID3  | 7   | 8   | 9  |
3|ID4  | 12  | 300 | 55 | 
4|ID5  | 0   | 1   | 2  |
```

df2:

```
       | A  |  B  | C |.......
------------------------------
Repeat | 10 | 2  | 50 |
```

df3:

```
                 | A    |  B   | C   |.......
------------------------------
Repeat w Addition| 100  | 200  | 500 |
```

what I'd like to do is create a new column in df1 with the values "Repeat", "Repeat with Addition" or "No" based on the following conditions

for each row if any value in cols A-C is greater than repeat addition = Repeat Addition
for each row if any value in cols A-C is greater than repeat but less than Repeat Addition= Repeat
else No

desired output:

df1:

```
 |Name | A   | B   | C  |.......|Repeat Required?|
--------------------------------------------------
0|ID1  | 10  | 2   | 3  |.......|     Repeat
1|ID2  | 400 | 1   | 6  |.......|     Repeat with Addition
2|ID3  | 7   | 8   | 9  |.......|     Repeat
3|ID4  | 12  | 300 | 55 |.......|     Repeat with Addition
4|ID5  | 0   | 1   | 2  |.......|     No
```

what I have so far:

I tried using a function with np.select to fill the column but it produces a bunch of No values when that is not correct

```
def repeat_required(df):
    conds = [df >= df3.loc["Repeat w Addition"], df>= df2.loc["Repeat"]]
    labels = ['Repeat with Dilution', 'Repeat']
    return np.select(conds, labels, default='No')

df1["Repeat Required?"]=""
df1["Repeat Required?"]=repeat_required(df1.iloc[:,4:-1]) #the first 4 columns contain strings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you want to use `np.select`, but the conditions you need to provide are Boolean Series that are the same length as `df1`. To do this, you need to compare with the rows in `df2` and `df3` as Series (so that it aligns on the columns) and then check if `any` of the values in df1 satisfy your conditions.

You can manually specify the columns to compare, as I do in a list below, or you can not specify anything and leverage the fact that `pandas` will automatically align for the `.ge` comparison so it would only consider overlapping columns for an `any` check.

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

conds = [df1[cols].ge(df3[cols].loc['Repeat w Addition']).any(1), 
         df1[cols].ge(df2[cols].loc['Repeat']).any(1)]
choices = ['Repeat w Addition', 'Repeat']

df1['Repeat Required'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='No')
```

---

```
print(df1)
  Name    A    B   C    Repeat Required
0  ID1   10    2   3             Repeat
1  ID2  400    1   6  Repeat w Addition
2  ID3    7    8   9             Repeat
3  ID4   12  300  55  Repeat w Addition
4  ID5    0    1   2                 No
```